# tornado - make connections survive server bounce

Tags: websocket, redis, tornado

I'm storing instances of `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` in a dictionary so when a message comes for a specific user I can route the message to the appropriate listener.

Implication of this is when the server bounces we lose the listener details and the client would have to create a new WebSocket instance.

I would like to implement means of storing the listener details in persistent store, maybe in redis but am unsure of best approach.

I could pickle the `WebSocketHandler` instance and write to redis, then read and unpickled when a message to a specific user needs to be routed to their client, but this feels a bit hacky. Is there a less hacky solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't usefully pickle the WebSocketHandler because connected sockets cannot be transferred in this way. You might be able to do something with a multiprocessing.Queue instead of simply pickling, but this will be tricky and hacky at best. Clients must be able to create new WebSocket connections in any case to recover from network outages; it's normal to simply do the same when the server restarts.